# SceneKit analogues for android without ARCore

Tags: android, 3d, rendering, scenekit, vuforia

There is a need to render 3D objects on a target from Vuforia. On iOS this allows SceneKit. Need support for lighting and materials. Are there any analogues of SceneKit for android?

edit:
I apologize, incorrectly asked a question. I'm looking for a lightweight engine (not a game engine) for rendering 3d objects on model view and projection matrices. Also need support for multitextures. Samples on pure opengl doesn't support multi-textures.

Comment: It is not really clear what it is you are asking. If it about rendering features, you can do whatever you wish, depends on how much effort you are willing to put, with OpenGL ES ...

Comment: I mean downloading and displaying a multitexture 3d object in the given coordinates (obtained with vuforia).

Comment: Of course, I would like to do this with minimal work with OpenGL

Comment: So look for proper open gl code or ask a more specific question... It has nothing to do with Vuforia

Comment: I apologize, incorrectly asked a question. I'm looking for a lightweight engine (not a game engine) for rendering 3d objects on model view and projection matrices. Also need support for multitextures.
Samples on pure opengl doesn't support multi-textures.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ViroCore: https://viromedia.com/virocore/

It's a scene-graph/SceneKit-like API we've created which serves as an analogue for SceneKit, but for Android.

The top level view you'd want to use is: https://developer.viromedia.com/virocore/reference/com/viro/core/ViroViewScene.html

We actually already have a developer [Streem.pro](https://www.streem.pro/) who is doing something similar to what you want, in that they're rendering over a camera feed using the `ViroViewScene` vs our ARCore-enabled `ViroViewARCore`.

Let us know if you have any issues!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at the ViroCore implementation, but I did not find it possible to render the object using model and projection matrices...

Comment: Hi @СерегаМахаев ahh, I was not aware of your requirements for that. We'll look into adding support for that in the future, thanks!